# Error on installing magento extension using Direct package file upload

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I try to install `Express Checkout | One Step Checkout` for `Magento Community Edition v1.7.0.2`. But it gives error:

```
CONNECT ERROR: Permission denied to write to var/package/tmp/\K:\xampp\htdocs\trial1\var
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved my problem. Instead of using a direct package file upload, I copy the extension to the Magento folder. Log out admin and login again, refresh cache if necessary.
But it doesn't display on Magento connect manager.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem about the folder permissions ;)
Check this [link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13646/setting-folder-to-be-writable-by-apache-php-in-windows)

Comment: I use xampp on windows 7, i use default configuration for magento connect. 
The right path is K:\xampp\htdocs\trial1\var, but it points to var/package/tmp/\K:\xampp\htdocs\trial1\var. 
I already change folder permission and clear read only attribute, but it still gives same error.